# Steps to create hash of hash in Perl script

Tags: regex, perl, file, hash

Method to create hash of hash below is the content of my file and when i open the my input file with below contents and we want to grep some data from the table such that i want to create a hash of hash of below pattern.

```
{
      'Golden' => {
                      'PT' => 80,
                      'po' => 43,
                      'DFF' => 139145,
                      'DLAT' => 276,
                      'Z' => 4,
                      'BBOX' => 833,
                      'Total' => 140387
                    },
      'Foo Bar' => {
                      'PT' => 80,
                      'po' => 43,
                      'DFF' => 139145,
                      'DLAT' => 276,
                      'Z' => 4,
                      'BBOX' => 833,
                      'Total' => 140387
                   }
    };
```

**FILE** content

Sample 1

```
 Mapped points: SYSTEM class
 Mapped points     PI     PO     BBOX      Total   
 Golden            86     43     833       140387  
 Revised           86     43     833       140387
```

Sample 2

```
 Mapped points: SYSTEM class
 Mapped points     PI     PO     DFF    DLAT   Z      BBOX      Total   
 Golden            86     43     139145 276    4      833       140387  
 Revised           86     43     139145 276    4      833       140387
```

and her's where i am stuck.

```
if ($line =~ m/^Mapped points: SYSTEM class$/){
    $var = "golden_mapped-points_PI";
    $hash{$var} = $6;
    next unless $line = <$filehandle> and $line =~ /^Mapped points     PI     PO     DFF    DLAT   Z      BBOX      Total   $/; 
}
```

and also in different input file number columns may change for example it may have only PI and PO in such situations i am not getting how to handle input files as well.

Comment: You need to create a [mcve] and clarify what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a copy of the headings line because the headings are the keys to your inner hash entries.  Once you start processing the data lines, you need to shift the first item off as its the key for your outer hash entry - a sort-of label for the line.  Once that's stored away, your headings and your data "line up";

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.12 ;
use Data::Dumper ;

my $starting_re = 'Mapped points: SYSTEM class' ;
my $headings_re = 'Mapped \s+ points \s+' ;
my %outer_hash;

# Find the starting line
while (<>) { last if /$starting_re/ }

# Read in one line.  Expect it to be the headings line
# Split it into pieces and store them for latter
my @headings ;
my $headings_line = <> ;
if ($headings_line =~ / $headings_re (.*) /x) {
    @headings = split ' ', $1 ;
}
else {
    say "Dont understand the headings line.";
    exit 1;
}

# Process each remaining line
while (<>) {
    # Split the data line and shift off
    # the first piece to use as a line label
    my @data = split ' ', $_;
    my $label = shift @data ;

    # Initialize a new inner hash and an index variable
    my %inner_hash = ();
    my $index = 0;

    # Iterate over the data pieces building up the hash
    for (@data) {
        $inner_hash{ $headings[$index] }  =  $_ ;
        $index++;
    }

    # Alternatively, build it with a hash slice
    # @inner_hash{ @headings }  =  @data ;

    # Create an entry in the outer hash by
    # taking a reference to our inner hash
    $outer_hash{ $label } = \%inner_hash;
}

say Dumper( \%outer_hash );
exit 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution using unpack. It handles any number of columns within different files.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;

my ($len, @hdrs);
my (@lengths, $template);

while (<DATA>) {
    next if 1 .. /^Mapped points:/;

    s/\s+$//; # safe 'chomp' (if there are spaces at end of string)

    if (s/^(Mapped points\s+)//) {
        $len = length $1;
        @hdrs = split;

        # lengths of all but the last (Total) field
        @lengths = map {length} /(\S+\s+)/g;

        # add 'A*' at the end to capture the 'Total' field
        $template = join("", "A$len", map {'A'. $_} @lengths) . "A*";
    }
    else {

        my ($key, @rest) = unpack $template;

        my %temp;
        @temp{ @hdrs } = @rest;
        $data{$key} = \%temp;
    }   
}
use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%data;

__DATA__
Mapped points: SYSTEM class
Mapped points     PI     PO     DFF    DLAT   Z      BBOX      Total
Golden            86     43     139145 276    4      833       140387
Revised           86     43     139145 276    4      833       140387
```

Output was:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Golden' => {
                        'Total' => '140387',
                        'BBOX' => '833',
                        'Z' => '4',
                        'PO' => '43',
                        'DLAT' => '276',
                        'DFF' => '139145',
                        'PI' => '86'
                      },
          'Revised' => {
                         'Total' => '140387',
                         'BBOX' => '833',
                         'Z' => '4',
                         'PO' => '43',
                         'DLAT' => '276',
                         'DFF' => '139145',
                         'PI' => '86'
                       }
        };
```

Answer (score -1):

I thought over and found a solution!! i know it's not the best solution yet and i request you to provide me the best possible solution

```
cat > test.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl  

use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>){
my $line = $_;
if ($line =~ m/^Mapped points: SYSTEM class$/){
    next unless $line = <DATA> and $line =~ /^Mapped points/; 
    my @arr = split(' ',$line);

    next unless $line = <DATA>;

    my @golden_arr = split(' ',$line);
    my $size1 = @golden_arr;
    for(my $i = 1;$i < $size1 ;$i++){
        my $var = "Golden_".$arr[$i+1];
        print "$var, $golden_arr[$i]\n";
    }
    next unless $line = <DATA>;
    my @revised_arr = split(' ',$line);
    my $size2 = @revised_arr;
    for(my $i = 1;$i < $size2 ;$i++){
        my $var = "Revised_".$arr[$i+1];
        print "$var, $revised_arr[$i]\n";
    }   
}
}


__DATA__

Mapped points: SYSTEM class
Mapped points     PI     PO     DFF    DLAT   Z      BBOX      Total   
Golden            86     43     139145 276    4      833       140387  
Revised           86     43     139145 276    4      833       140387  

perl test.pl
Golden_PI, 86
Golden_PO, 43
Golden_DFF, 139145
Golden_DLAT, 276
Golden_Z, 4
Golden_BBOX, 833
Golden_Total, 140387
Revised_PI, 86
Revised_PO, 43
Revised_DFF, 139145
Revised_DLAT, 276
Revised_Z, 4
Revised_BBOX, 833
Revised_Total, 140387
```

Any better solution?